# TextView not getting SetOnClck Listener call after Localisation in android

Tags: android, localization, onclicklistener

changed Language by Clicking TextView.
after Changing Language TextView not getting Call inside SetOnClick Listener.

```
 tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                changeLanguage();
            }
        });
```

.................................

```
 private void changeLanguage() {
        Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.setLocale(locale);
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

    }
```

Comment: are you sure it does not go inside changeLanguage method?

Comment: yes @BorisRuzanov